# How to concatenate timestamp in curl header?

Tags: bash, curl

I am trying to send a request in curl and trying to insert current timestamp in the cookie

```
curl -v 'https://example.com'
-H $'cookie: ts=1601356520581'
```

How to insert the `date +%s%3N` in place of the hardcoded value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a POSIX shell (sh, bash, zsh, etc), you can expand your command with the syntaxis `$(command)`. For example:

```
curl -v "https://example.com" -H "cookie: ts=$(date +%s%3N)"
```